# ggplot2 and R - Applying custom colors to a multi group histogram in long format

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, histogram

I've made a histogram graph that shows the distribution of lidar returns per elevation for three lidar scans I have done.

I've converted my data to long format, with:

- one  column called 'value', describing the z position of each point
- one column called 'variable', containing the name of each
  scan group

In the attached image you can see the histograms of my three scan groups. I am currently  using viridis to color the histogram by scan group (ie. the name of the scan in the variable column). However, I want to match the colours in the graph with colours I already have.

How might I do this?

The hexcols I'd like to like color each of my three histograms with are:

```
lightgreen = "#62FE96"
lightred = "#FE206B"
darkpurple = "#62278E"
```

[A link to my data - 'density2'](https://unimelbcloud-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/alex_holland_unimelb_edu_au/ERiO9GQFGYNLoy3rdMkEmEMBmzr5tMOe61Irehc5bSgc9w?e=4h7UCx)

[image]

My current code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(viridisLite)
library(viridis)

# histogram
p <- density2 %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=value,color = variable, show.legend = FALSE)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, alpha = 0.5, position="identity") +
  scale_color_viridis(discrete =TRUE) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(fill="") +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

p + scale_y_sqrt() + theme(legend.position="none") + labs(y = "data pts", x = "elevation (m)")
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `scale_color_viridis` and `scale_fill_viridis` lines - these are applying the Viridis color scale. Replace with `scale_fill_manual(values = c(lightgreen, lightred, darkpurple))`. And in your aesthetic mapping replace `color = variable` with `fill = variable`. For a histogram, `color` refers to the color of the lines outlining each bar, and `fill` refers to the color each bar is filled in.

This should leave you with:

```
p <- density2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, alpha = 0.5, position = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(lightgreen, lightred, darkpurple)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(fill = "") +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())

p + scale_y_sqrt() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(y = "data pts", x = "elevation (m)")
```

I've also done some other clean-up. `show.legend = FALSE` does not belong inside `aes()` - and your `theme(legend.position = "none")` should take care of it.

I did not download your data, save it in my working directory, import it into R, and test this code on it. If you need more help, please post a small subset of your data in a copy/pasteable format (e.g., `dput(density2[1:20, ])` for the first 20 rows---choose a suitable subset) and I'll be happy to test and adjust.